# Creating buffer doughnuts in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I have tried Multiple Buffer in ArcMap and I get this image. What I want however is the interval between buffers. I.e. 0-10, 11-20, 21-30 meters.

This tool just uses the point as origin. Hopefully I made my question clear enough.

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you asking. Your results already contain intervals isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the buffers are still originating from the point. I want the intervals like this " 0-10, 11-20, 21-30 meters.", In my example the buffers are "0-10, 0-20, 0-30".

Comment: There is `Dissolve_option` parameter in `Multiple buffer ring` tool. Try to set it to `ALL`.  Also you can try to use `Outside_polygons_only` parameter.

Comment: Thank you ALL solved the problem by then exporting the specific entries in the attribute table. Outside_polygons_only doesn't work with point features unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [Multiple Ring Buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm) tool. Just input the point feature class and set the distances. Unless you are using a field with distance remove any field name from Field Name optional. Set Dissolve to ALL.

If you want the intervals as different feature classes use the normal [Buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) process and use the output from each process as the input for the next setting Side Type to Outside_Only

Comment: That is greyed out since I'm using point data as input for the buffers.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is similar to Mr. Che. I wasn't sure what you meant with the second part of your answer though.

Comment: I wasn't sure from your question what exactly you wanted. The second part is if you want each ring as a separate feature class. You just buffer the original point. Then buffer that buffer to the outside only and so on.

Comment: Aha, I did that by selecting features from the attribute table and then export them.

Comment: That will work too :)